# How much new initialize the memory to object?

Tags: c++

we know that malloc gives unintialize memory, whereas calloc initialize memory with zero. So what value does new operator in c++ gives When it initialize the object??

Comment: It calls the object's default constructor.

Comment: Also at compile time your object should be computed in size (with some exceptions), so it will allocate memory (in program heap as I remember) and call the constructor, I think.

Comment: Try this if you're feeling masochistic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/1171191

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there is a constructor for the object, it will call the default constructor.

But objects such as `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, all forms of pointers, and such like, do not have default constructor [or an "empty" default constructor], so nothing gets done for those - you get whatever happens to be in the memory that `new` got for you - which may be zeros or some old gunk from a previous allocation.

You can, if you specifically want to, use the "value initialize" for memory block created by `new`, e.g. `int *a = new int[size]();` [zero initializes].

Comment: Although you can chose to value-initialize the built-ins: `int* i = new int();`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Good point - added a section about that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: are you sure about that `12`? I thought it's only possible to zero the array.

Comment: @podkova: Correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

New basically calls an object constructor and its up to you how you want to initialize your object. If you don't initialize it, you will get garbage values on accessing